# How to store input data as objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, use-state

How do I store the input data as objects in an array using `useState`? Please help.
I need help. I am not able to get the desired output to display the input values.

```
const Form = () => {
      const [allNotes, setAllNotes] = useState([{}]);
      const [notes, setNotes] = useState({
        name: "",
        age: "",
        class: "",
        request: "",
      });
    
      const nameChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setNotes((prevState) => {
          const newState = { ...prevState, name: event.target.value };
          return newState;
        });
      };
      const ageChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setNotes((prevState) => {
          const newState = { ...prevState, age: event.target.value };
          return newState;
        });
      };
      const classChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setNotes((prevState) => {
          const newState = { ...prevState, class: event.target.value };
          return newState;
        });
      };
      const requestChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setNotes((prevState) => {
          const newState = { ...prevState, request: event.target.value };
          return newState;
        });
      };
    
      const submitHandler = () => {
        setAllNotes((prevState) => {
          const newState = {
            ...prevState,
            name: notes.name,
            age: notes.age,
            class: notes.class,
            request: notes.request,
          };
          return newState;
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good, maybe except for two small mistakes:

- Let's make the initial state for `all notes` just an empty array, like

  `const [allNotes, setAllNotes] = useState([]);`
- The new array inside the `setAllNotes` should be **array** not **object**, like:

```
    const submitHandler = () => {
      setAllNotes((prevState) => {
        const newState = [
          ...prevState,
          {
            name: notes.name,
            age: notes.age,
            class: notes.class,
            request: notes.request,
          }
        ];
        return newState;
      });
    };
```

Hope this makes it work!

Comment: Thanks @Yasser hennawi
It works fine now.